# Jetty/SOLR Admin Panel Password

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I am applying authentication on SOLR Admin Panel using jetty. I have read so many tutorials and implemented using following steps:

Added following code in /solr/core/etc/jetty.xml :

```
   <Call name="addBean">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
      <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
      <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/var/www/solr/core/etc/realm.properties</Set>
      <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Added following code in /solr/core/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>

  </login-config>
```

And then created file realm.proprerties file in solr/core/etc with following line of code:

```
admin: OBF:1y0s1v1p1v2p1y0y, admin
```

But when I open solr admin panel using URL http://localhost:8983/solr/. I got a popup asking username and password. I fill username and password as I have added in realm.properties. But unable to login.

Please help me figuring out where I am wrong.

Comment: Putting the relative path instead of the absolute path into `<SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>...</Set>` solved it for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your realm.properties file define the user as:

`<username>: <password>, <role>`

`ex: admin: 12345, admin`

Also check your `"jetty.home"` path. It should be the 'etc' directory in your SOLR core folder.

Also in realm.properties you should enter your password after hashing & for this there is a default SOLR utility which can be used as:

`java -cp jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password <username> <password>`

ex: `java -cp jetty-util-8.1.10.v20130312.jar org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Password admin 12345`

**Output**:

`12345
OBF:19bv19bx19bz19c119c3
MD5:827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
CRYPT:adpliAB3dA.06`

You can use any of the three forms in properties file along with their type as:

`admin: MD5:827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b, admin`

Hope this might help!

Comment: Will this work for solr5 and above?
I tried this and it gave a error `!role`

Comment: @nikhil24, haven't tried on SOLR5. BTW, have you defined the role in your web.xml file and is it same as your realm.properties file?

Comment: @nikhil24, try following the instructions given here (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin)

Comment: The solution on the official page can be implemented only on SolrCloud using Apache Zookeeper. I just wanted to see if I can bypass this and yet implement a password, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @NikhilSahu, confirming this is solution is working with solr 5.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Obfuscated password are not completely supported.

I can confirm that in SOLR 6.4.1 in Cloud Mode with build in Zookeeper, OBF passwords are partially supported. SOLR starts, the Admin UI works, but some of the other API's fail with an error indicating the passwords are incorrect.

[SOLR-8897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8897)

We use an official certificate, not self signed.

Only clear text passwords seem to work in our instance.